# Orders of release or order of release

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In the following sentence :

> The magistrate passed order of his release.

Should I use plural form of order, that is, "orders"? If yes, then why? What does exactly "orders" will mean in this particular sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. You could say:

> The magistrate passed *an* **order** *for* his release.

or

> The magistrate passed **orders** *for* his release.

[***order***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/order) as used here means:

> 10) a command, direction, or instruction, usually backed by authority

Such instructions could be singular or plural, depending on context.

Also use [***for***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/for):

> 5) with the aim or for the purpose of

since the purpose of the orders is to get him released.